# Is it possible to have more than one password with js encryption?

Tags: javascript, html, passwords

I am currently using an encryptor project on my website. https://robinmoisson.github.io/staticrypt/

It encrypts HTML files and shows a password prompt and when the password is guessed right it decrypts the website.

My question is, is it possible to have more than one password with this project. Instead of having only one password? I would like it to work with multiple passwords.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question are because you didn't know how the encryption systems works.

You cannot use multiple different passwords, because the password itself are literally the key of the encrypted content.

If you use a different password for encrypt content, then you have a different result (a different encrypted result). Because this, you cannot have multiple passwords for decrypt the same data.

The only option, if you want to have different passwords, is to process it at server level. The client sends a password, these password are processed at server side, and if the password are valid (you can have a database with passwords for a user or a list of valid passwords), then you send the content. You can also use a system to send the decryption password to the client, encrypted with a user-level password. For example:

> - The client fills a username field. These field are sent to server. Server retrieves the password for these user from a storage at server
>     side, and then, encrypt content with these password. At last, the
>     content is sent to the client encrypted with the user password, who
>     will need to enter it to read these content.

I think these method are the best method to achieve what do you need. But I understand is not your request, is an approach to do it.